# Calling Assembly Functions in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am playing around trying to call assembly functions I have written in Nasm within C. For some reason things are not behaving as I am expecting.

```
NASM:

SECTION .DATA
  hello: db 'Hello', 0x0a ; Hello/n

SECTION .TEXT
  global sayHello

sayHello:
  mov rax, 4           ; write()
  mov rbx, 1           ; stdout
  mov rcx, hello       ; add hello to register
  mov rdx, 6           ; length of string
  int 0x80             ; interrupt
  ret                  ; return
```

```
C:

#include <stdio.h>

extern int sayHello();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  printf("ASM Function is saying Hello:\n");
  sayHello();
  

  return 0;
}
```

compiled with: nasm -f elf64 and gcc

result:

```
ASM Function is saying Hello:
```

expected result:

```
ASM Function is saying Hello:
Hello
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Modern GCC makes PIE executables so the string address will be outside the low 32 bits.  Truncating it to 32-bit with the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI will make `write` return `-EFAULT`.  Use `strace` or a debugger (like GDB) to single-step your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a 32-bit syscall in a 64-bit program.

That *works* on Linux, but only if your pointers fit in 32 bits! They probably **don't** (check the address of `hello`) otherwise you will probably get EFAULT (because the address is truncated, and probably points to unmapped memory).

### Making a 64-bit syscall

- Use the correct registers for 64-bit (`rax`, `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`)
- You need to use the 64-bit syscall numbers (`asm/unistd_64.h` defines `__NR_write` 1, consider using `#include` if possible).
- Use `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`.

Comment: The x86-64 SysV `syscall` calling convention is similar to the function-calling convention, with args in EDI, RSI, RDX (in that order).  Only the 32-bit ABI makes the unfortunate choice of EBX (a call-preserved register) as the first arg, which makes libc wrapper functions less efficient.

Comment: Gah, thanks. I should go to bed.